# Ответ от функции с замыканием, как дождаться ответа а потом отправить результат?

Tags: swift, rabbitmq

Не могу найти решения своей проблемы:
Необходимо дождаться ответа от замыкания в функции, подскажите как это сделать?
Вот код:

```
import Foundation
import RMQClient
import SwiftyJSON

func getMessage() -> [String:Any] {
        var answer: [String:Any] = [:]
        let conn = RMQConnection(uri: "amqp://\(self.login):\(self.password)@\(self.ip1):\(self.port1)", delegate: RMQConnectionDelegateLogger())
        conn.start()
        let ch = conn.createChannel()
        let q = ch.queue("client_" + String(self.phoneNumber), options: .autoDelete)
        ch.queueBind("client_" + String(self.phoneNumber), exchange: "sysPay", routingKey: String(self.phoneNumber))

q.subscribe({(_ message: RMQMessage) -> Void in
            print("Received \(String(data: message.body, encoding: .utf8))")
            let json = try? JSON(message.body)
            answer["type"] = message.messageType()
            for (key, value) in (json?.dictionary)! {
                answer[key] = value
            }
            if answer.count <= 0 {
                answer["type"] = "no_connect"
            }
        })
return answer
    }
```

return всегда срабатывает раньше получения ответа из замыкания!
А тут `q.subscribe({(_ message: RMQMessage) -> Void` результат может быть только void.

Подскажите как дождаться результата из замыкания а потом вернуть результат из функции?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Результат выполнения приходит в `q.subscribe` позже, потому, что запрос выполняется асинхронно. В этом случае лучше всего возвращать ответ тоже асинхронно:

```swift
func getMessage(_ callback: @escaping ([String: Any]) -> Void) { // callback - это функция, которую надо вызвать при получении ответа
    ...
    q.subscribe {(_ message: RMQMessage) -> Void in // Подписываемся на результат
        ....
        DispatchQueue.main.async { // На всякий случай переводим выполнение в главный поток
            callback(answer) // Возвращаем результат
        }
    }
}
```

Придется также поменять код вызова метода. Если ранее у Вас было:

```swift
let messageData = getMessage() // Вызываем фукнкцию и получаем результат
print(messageData)             // Выводим результат на экран
```

То с асинхронным вариантом это выглядит следующим образом:

```swift
getMessage { messageData in // Вызываем фукнкцию и получаем результат
    print(messageData)      // Выводим результат на экран
}
```

Comment: А можно, как-то добавить сюда же таймаут? т.е. через 10 секунд если от замыкания нет результата то выходим из функции?

Comment: И еще при вызове: getMessage { messageData in // Вызываем фукнкцию и получаем результат
    print(messageData) print("111")      // Выводим результат на экран
} print("222") выведется сначало "222" получается а потом "111" ? И всю обработку результата нужно делать в замыкании, я правильно понял?

Comment: Да, Вы правильно поняли, всю обработку результата надо делать в замыкании, оно вызывается когда получен ответ.

Comment: Можно сделать timeout тоже с помощью функции `Dispatch.asyncAfter(.now() + 10) { ... } `. Внутри стоит отметить, что callback при получении результата вызывать не надо и вызвать callback с `nil`. Это как пример. Возможно у Вашей библиотеки есть более хороший способ остановить выполнение запроса.

Comment: Увы приведенный Вами код второй раз не срабатывает! - ответ не приходит! Все хорошо только при первом запуске! Почему так?

Comment: Возможно это как-то связано с реализацией соединений в библиотеке `RMQClient` ‍♂️ . К сожалению, я с ней не работал, поэтому не могу точно сказать. Попробуйте поставить брекпоинты и посмотреть, что все вызовы внутри `getMessage` во второй раз проходят так-же как и в первый. Так вы сможете разделить свою логику с логикой библиотеки и понять, где что-то идет не так.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал функцию глобальной:

```
func globalGetMessage2(_ callback: @escaping ( (JSON) -> Void) )  {
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 9, repeats: false) { _ in
    callback(JSON())
}
    print("global getMessage2")
    let session = Session.instance
    let conn = RMQConnection(uri: "amqp://\(session.login):\(session.password)@\(session.ip1):\(session.port1)", delegate: RMQConnectionDelegateLogger())
    conn.start()
    let ch = conn.createChannel()
    let q = ch.queue("client_" + String(session.phoneNum), options: .autoDelete)
    ch.queueBind("client_" + String(session.phoneNum), exchange: "sysPay", routingKey: String(session.phoneNum))
    print("Waiting for messages2.")

    q.subscribe({(_ message: RMQMessage) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        var json = JSON()
            print("Received global: \(String(data: message.body, encoding: .utf8))")
            json = try! JSON(message.body)
        json["type"].stringValue = message.messageType()
        conn.close()
timer.invalidate()
            callback(json)
            }
        })
    }
```

Все встало на свои места!

Вот как еще и с таймаутом!

Спасибо.

Comment: Вы дали ответ, но он содержит вопрос. Ответить вам в этой теме никто не сможет. Задайте новый вопрос и сошлитесь на текущий.